# Is it good practice to have each typedef in separate file?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I've read somewhere, that it's good to have each `typedef` in separate file, but it wasn't even explained.

For example like this:

```
#ifndef _MYTYPEDEF_H
#define _MYTYPEDEF_H
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

typedef std::pair<unsigned short, int>  my_typedef;

#endif //_MYTYPEDEF_H
```

But I think it will be a mess if I have for example 50 `typedef`s in my project, so there would be 50 files just for them.

Comment: I've never seen/heard such thing. Sounds ridiculous to me.

Comment: *Might* be a better question for Programmers. Not sure you'll be getting a technical answer to a technical problem with this question (though I don't have an answer, so maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: It's usually good practice to use a single header for a single class, or for a small but tightly related set of classes. For typedefs? Not so much.

Comment: If you do, please do not include iostream in these files

Comment: @user877329 What's the reason for that?

Comment: Because the typedef doesn't need it. And it is a good practice to not include more than nessecary. But in this example, you should include the header for std::pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only obfuscates the code and confuses the one who maintains(*which is not usually the one who invents such fancy ideas*) it.
This is only good(*if at all*) for the developer who only sees single TUs during development but not for the one who maintains it and sees the entire code base post development.
Please don't do it at all.